# how to change url to be as fancybox inner url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, fancybox, fancybox-2

Im useing `facybox 2.1.5` to show an `iframe`, and i need the `url`
be same as the url inside fancybox, which need to be dynamic.

For example, if i open `www.wikipedia.com` in fancybox my `url` should be
`www.wikipedia.com`, and if in wikipedia i will click some other link my `url` has to change properly without refreshing the page (`www.wikipedia.com/something`).

**Update**, and when i will close the fancybox my url will back to normal.

**Assume, in wikipedia the `url` and the content is changing witheout refreshing (`ajax`).

Here some code of mine:

```
          $('.fancybox').fancybox
          ({
                type: "iframe",
                padding: 0,
                fitToView: false,
                autoSize: false,
                 'scrolling'   : 'no',
                wrapCSS: 'fancybox-custom',
                closeClick: true,
                openEffect: 'none',
                helpers: 
                   {
                    title: {
                        type: 'inside'
                           },
                    overlay: 
                             {
                        css: 
                         {
                            'background': 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                         }
                             }
                    },

               beforeShow: function () 
                {
                  this.width = '60%'; 
                    this.height = ($('.fancybox-iframe').contents().find('body').height()) + 500;
                }

            });
```

Comment: But you said you are using `iframe`, It does that.

Comment: can u help me ?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149680/history-pushstate-eror-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-a-history?lq=1
@Manoz

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("FrameID").src`
This function can be used to get the url out of an i-frame. you can update your url with value returned by this function.

you can use change of url returned by the function as a trigger

```
var _url
_url = document.getElementById("FrameID").src;
function do(){
   if(_url != document.getElementById("FrameID").src){
        //update url here
   }
   setTimeOut("do()",1000);
}
```

Comment: can u help me please?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28149680/history-pushstate-eror-failed-to-execute-pushstate-on-history-a-history?lq=1
@PrakharSingh